# How to scroll to a page with button pressed event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I use this sample application for create a scrollview with pages.

https://github.com/cwalcott/UIScrollView-Paging

It works great. But I want to do is **Scroll to specific page, when a button pressed**. I tried to do so by re-calling `-(void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page` method in my button pressed method.

```
-(void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page method in my button pressed method.
    PagesViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        NSArray *arrTemp = [dicObjectSet objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", page]];
        //NSLog(@" Arrewrtwr : %@", arrTemp);
        controller = [[PagesViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page arrObject:arrTemp];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }
```

, but I failed.

Can you please give me a help.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: really sorry for not putting my work, what I tried was, re-call -(void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page in the button pressed method

Comment: either I messed something up while trying to format your code or half the method is missing.

Comment: I have messed with it, its rather easy. I did it like this.       CGRect frame = viewScrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * [sender tag];
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [viewScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
                                                                                        thanks a lot for all you for the look at